# How to get database name in PDO?

Tags: php, database, pdo

```
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=testdb;host=127.0.0.1';
$user = 'dbuser';
$password = 'dbpass';

try {
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Is there a function or constant within PDO that stores the database name (the `testdb` value) ? I did a var_dump on $dbh and cant find anything...

Answer (score -10, accepted):

You could use the `setAttribute()` (essentially a key value pair) method to store the database name when you set it up initially, then use the `getAttribute()` later in your code to see what the value is.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.setattribute.php

Comment: This doesn't work as expected since PDO::setAttribute accepts only an integer as key. Defining your own constant could do it but it's a little tricky. look here: `http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.setattribute.php`

Comment: What a wrong guessed answer ... - PHP also has dynamic public properties you can set at runtime - no need for `setAttribute()` or `getAttribute()`, just doing à la `$pdo->myDataBaseNameProperty = 'dbame';`  would suffice.

Comment: 3 years later, and my (accepted) answer hasn't stood the test of time. There is a clearly better answer below that I'd recommend.

Answer (score 46):

Given you're on mysql, you can do [`select database()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_database) to get the name of the default database.

```
/* @var $pdo PDO */
$pdo->query('select database()')->fetchColumn();
```

Comment: Normally I wouldn't have used this, but in certain situations where you can't extend the PDO code, this will work.

Answer (score 13):

Nope, there is no built-in feature.

But you can extend `class MyPdo extends PDO`, parse and store dsn and return it by some accessor

```
class MyPdo extends PDO
{
    ...

    /**
     * @param string $dsnParameter
     * @param string|null $default
     * @throws RuntimeException
     * @return string|null
     */
    public function getDsnValue($dsnParameter, $default = NULL)
    {
        $pattern = sprintf('~%s=([^;]*)(?:;|$)~', preg_quote($dsnParameter, '~'));

        $result = preg_match($pattern, $this->dsn, $matches);
        if ($result === FALSE) {
            throw new RuntimeException('Regular expression matching failed unexpectedly.');
        }

        return $result ? $matches[1] : $default;
    }

    ...
```

Comment: I would definitely not recommend parsing, if he extends, he should add a member for database name which he could refer to.

Comment: Just added some code. Not that it is totally extensively tested, I have written this some weeks ago and uses, just was looking again about the problem and as it didn't bring me into problems, posting it as an example here. It's not written after any specs, but does work so far, esp. for getting the database name from DSN.